# Override ion-content's background color

Tags: sass, ionic2, background-color, ion-content

We set ion-content's background color in app.scss or wherever. How can I override it? When I put this into the page's scss:

```
#page-content {
    background-color: purple;
}
```

Nothing happens. (Of course I added the id to the tag: `<ion-content padding id="page-content">`)

Answer (score 1):

You should use color in RGB code.

```
background-color: #000000;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it with add **!important**

```
#page-content {
    background-color: purple!important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I changed the background:

```
.scroll-content {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Global scss or local scss mention this

> ion-content{
>       --background:white }